# How to append to html an owl-carousel with products w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to append my products to an owl-carousel from javascript but when i append it displays my owl-carousel like this:
[image]

While owl-carousel should be:

[image: ----------]

So my HTML code is:

```
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5"  data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="cs-pic">
          <div class="effect">
          <div class="listProduct">
            <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
            Electrical
          </h4>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cs-pic">
          <div class="effect">
          <div class="listProduct">
            <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
            Electrical
          </h4>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cs-pic">
          <div class="effect">
          <div class="listProduct">
            <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
            Electrical
          </h4>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cs-pic">
          <div class="effect">
          <div class="listProduct">
            <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
            Electrical
          </h4>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="cs-pic">
          <div class="effect">
          <div class="listProduct">
            <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
            Electrical
          </h4>     
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My Javacsript code:

```
 sectionCarouselProducts.innerHTML = sectionCarouselProducts.innerHTML + `
    <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="cs-pic">
    <div class="effect">
    <div class="listProduct">
      <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
          <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
          <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
          <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <img src="${product.img}" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
      ${product.title}
    </h4>     
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  `
```

Btw, i append my inner html to this html:

```
    <div class="container mt-5 mb-5"  data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center">
  <div class="owl-carousel carousel-products">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

So in conclusion why my owl carousel when i append it displays vertical and not carousel? Thank you for your help! For further information you can tell me to edit it!

Comment: owl-carousel requires JQuery I think and won't work with just vanilla JS

Comment: You could try out this --> https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider it is inspired by owl-carousel and should work for your use case.

Comment: @SiddharthSeth Tiny Slider is very good carousel but still my append dont work as i want

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var slider = tns({
    container: '.my-slider',
    items: 1,
    responsive: {
      640: {
        edgePadding: 20,
        gutter: 20,
        items: 2
      },
      700: {
        gutter: 30
      },
      900: {
        items: 3
      }
    }
  });





<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5"  data-aos-anchor-placement="top-center">
      <div class="my-slider">
      <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="cs-pic">
              <div class="effect">
              <div class="listProduct">
                <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                    <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
                Electrical
              </h4>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="cs-pic">
              <div class="effect">
              <div class="listProduct">
                <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                    <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
                Electrical
              </h4>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="cs-pic">
              <div class="effect">
              <div class="listProduct">
                <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                    <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
                Electrical
              </h4>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="cs-pic">
              <div class="effect">
              <div class="listProduct">
                <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                    <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
                Electrical
              </h4>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-2 mr-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="cs-pic">
              <div class="effect">
              <div class="listProduct">
                <div class="product-action-list d-flex">
                    <a  href="product.php" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Add to Favorites"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></a>
                    <a href="login.php" title="Email me When the price drops"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span></a>
                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              <img src="imgProducts/guitar1.jpg" alt="Product" class="card-img-top">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title text-center">    
                Electrical
              </h4>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
```

Here is an example with your setup ... Hope it helps...